# How to rebase all commits of a Gerrit review at once without losing +2 votes?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a change with several commits, e.g.:

- last
- second
- first

I have received +2 for merging, but unfortunately master has moved, and one of the commits shows as "merge conflict", so I can't submit all commits at once.

However, when I try to rebase locally, the rebase is trivial. And also, if I use Rebase on the web interface, it successfully resolves the conflict.

The problem with rebasing locally however, is that I would lose the +2 votes, and have to annoy reviewers again.

The web interface does conserve my +2 votes, but I haven't found a way to rebase all commits at once: the best I could do was:

- rebase `first` on the new master
- rebase `second` on top of first with `Rebase on parent change`
- and so on until the final commit

If I try to rebase the last commit directly on the web UI, as I would do from the CLI, Gerrit warns me that this would break the relation chain:

```
Rebase on top of the master branch (breaks relation chain)
```

which I think means only one commit will go on top of master, and not rebase as I want?

Is there a way to rebase all at once, without losing my +2 votes?

Tested on Gerrit 2.16.2.

Comment: I can't understand your question because it seems you aren't using correct Gerrit terms. You can't have a "patchset with several commits" because "patchset" and "commit" is exactly the same. Do you mean you have a "change with several commits (patchsets)"? Or you have several changes?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira yes, thanks, one change with multiple commits. I'm not very familiar with Gerrit terminology. Updated question.

Answer (score 4):

When you have one change with several patchsets (commits) you don't need to rebase each commit, you just need to rebase the last commit. Actually you're going to submit (integrate/merge) just the last commit not the whole chain. Every time you amend a patchset you create a new commit that replaces the previous one.

If you're confused with this concept it's good to read the [Working with Gerrit: An example](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-gerrit-walkthrough.html) item in Gerrit documentation.

Answering your question: When you rebase a patchset, Gerrit will treat the +1/+2 votes according to the [copyAllScoresOnTrivialRebase](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_copyAllScoresOnTrivialRebase) configuration of the project. If true, all scores for the label are copied forward when a new patch set is uploaded that is a trivial rebase. There's no difference in how this works if the rebase is made manually and pushed or made using the Web UI. If you're getting a different behavior make sure you're not changing the commit message.

> A new patch set is considered as trivial rebase if the commit message
>   is the same as in the previous patch set and if it has the same code
>   delta as the previous patch set.

Comment: OK, so if I rebase the last it will work then. I'll try that out next time. I was afraid it would do something weird due to the "breaks relation chain" part of the description. I didn't know there was a setting for keeping the +2, but that must be turned on in my instance so it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try

1. git checkout master
2. git pull -> This pulls the latest code from remote master to your local master branch.
3. git checkout your_branch_name.
4. git rebase origin/master.

Resolve merge conflicts and update your review request.

Comment: If I do that I believe I lose +2 votes as mentioned on question.

Comment: Yes you would lose +2 because you would be sending a new patchset after resolving merge conflicts. Probably there needs to be a feature request on Gerrit if not already to preserve votes in case the commit ID is same, as rebasing the branch with master will not alter the commit ID I believe... :)

Comment: Rebasing will change commit SHAs since the parent commit SHAs change. Perhaps it's dependent on the Gerrit config, but in my experience the +2 reviews are not dismissed unless you actually made changes (e.g. resolving conflicts).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do that. Editing commits (and rebase is editing) means that the commits need new review.

My experience says you shouldn't push new commits for review until the last one was completed and pushed further.

Comment: I can understand that rationale, but it is worth noting that rebase on web interface does keep the +2 votes.